# Select2 works on fiddle not on localserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I wanted to use Select2 (Source: https://select2.github.io/) for selecting and tagging purpose.

Went through an example on 
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcusasplund/jEADR/2/) and tried to replicate it on my local server (xampp). Here is the code, which is exactly the same as on the fiddle.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
<option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
<option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<script>
$("#e1").select2();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the code on the fiddle works but the same exact thing on my localserver doesn't.

Why?

Comment: include jquery library file

Comment: @vinox, the fiddle external resources has two files included, select2.css and select2.js but no jquery file. I even included the jquery file via cdn yet it did not work

Comment: include Jquery library file before select2 js

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Type of error? (Get from console)

Comment: @vinox, it worked. Thank you. Answer it on the main so i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include jquery library file
 before Select2.js file